# Postgres Database Not In/Not Equals Queries Behave as SELECT *

Tags: sql, postgresql

I believe the below two SQL statements are formulated correctly. I am seeking all entries in the database except for those 7 Countries listed in the query below. However, the query returns all entries in the database, including entries from the below countries. I am sure the schema is set up properly and that data points with these 'Subject Country' fields do exist. When I try to select only those countries or a subset, I am able to retrieve just those entries. The 'Subject Country' field is a text field.

```
\copy (SELECT * FROM prod."Countries" 
WHERE 'Subject Country'
NOT IN ('CN', 'HK', 'JP', 'KR','TW','TH','VN'))
TO 'C:\tmp\CountriesMinus.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;

\copy (SELECT * FROM prod."Countries" 
WHERE Subject Country' != 'CN' 
AND 'Subject Country' != 'HK' 
AND 'Subject Country' != 'JP' 
AND 'Subject Country' != 'KR' 
AND 'Subject Country' != 'TW' 
AND 'Subject Country' != 'TH' 
AND 'Subject Country' != 'VN') 
To 'C:\tmp\CountriesMinus.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: You have `'` around the column name `Subject Country` which means that you're telling the database that you're giving it a literal string.  This means that you're asking `WHERE 'string1' NOT IN ('string2', 'string3', 'string4')`.  As the string `'Subject Country'` never appaears in your list, the term is always true, and you get every row...  Try using `"Subject Country"` instead?  Or, even better, remove the space from the column name in your table, and just use `subject_country` or `subjectCountry`?